How to retrieve large number of rows more quickly?
Attempting to convert a binary file to an sqlite3 database one challenge is performance. A first query returns 42,000 rows in less than a millisecond. Surprising as the query includes selecting rows then joining those with two other tables. I fetch/step through each row in about .33 milliseconds, .33 * 42,000 is about 19 seconds.
The binary file implementation loads in under a second. Is there any way to speed up these steps? Ideally fetch more than one row at a time. Python sqlite3 has fetch_all() and fetch_many() fetching multiple rows but C++ doesn't.
I removed the step calls and spun my while loop 42,000 times to make sure the performance bottleneck was in the step. This confirmed that the steps are slowing things down.

it sounds like it's able to use the index to determine the rows that satisfy the query. You hit the bottleneck when it needs to fetch all the row data. Make sure you use specific column names in the SELECT list, rather tha SELECT *, if you only need a few columns.

Each time you call sqlite3_step() it computes the next result row, which can definitely be slow when joining multiple tables due to how it works internally. Python's fetch_all() just does that in a loop appending results to a list.

The sqlite3_prepare_xxx() functions (which I assume is what you're talking about with "first query") don't fetch any data from the DB; they just compile a SQL statement to sqlite3's internal bytecode.

Show code, database schema and query plan please.

Thanks all for the comments.  It does look like this is just a performance attribute of Sqlite and maybe databases in general.  Our challenge is the db implementation needs to come close to the performance of the in-house developed custom data handling which is likely impossible.
